# How to select an already created random true Boolean variable?

Tags: java, random, boolean

Lets say I have four Boolean Variables,

```java
Boolean a;
Boolean b;
Boolean c;
Boolean d;
```

Now, before I select one of these variables, I run a function to find out if they are `true` or `false` (it's not relevant *why* they are `true` or `false`).

So lets say:

```java
a = false;
b = true;
c = false;
d = true;
```

Now, because `b` and `d` are `true`, I want to randomly select one of those two; and, if three variables are `true`, then I would want to randomly select one from those three.

I am lost how I would be able to accomplish this.

Comment: If you want to pick from your four values, including only the ones that are true, then you want to always randomly pick the value `true`?... otherwise, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: How you differentiate which one selected?

Comment: Do you have a fixed amount of boolean variables?

Comment: What happens if none of them are true?

Comment: Ic. So you want to randomly select any of the variables that are true? I would create the variables as Objects: `new Boolean(initvalue)`. Then have a function that gets an array of these objects and randomly selects one of those that happen to be true.

Comment: Do you expect this new GetRandomVariable() function to return a boolean, or a char representing the name of the variable?  (a,b,c or d?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class java.util.Random and generate a random number and set the bound to 1. Then it generates 0 or 1. Now you can check, if the random number is 0 or 1 and if it's 0 you select b and if its 1 you select d. And the same with 3 Booleans that are true.

```
// Import the class
import java.util.Random;

// Create an Instance of Random
Random r = new Random();

// Generate a random number between 0 and 1
short randomNumber = r.nextInt(1);

if (randomNumber == 0)
{
    // do something with b     
}

if (randomNumber == 1)
{
    // do something with d     
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you try to select somehow a specific `Boolean` variable (a, b, c, d).
However, if unboxed `boolean` values are assigned to `Boolean` variable, they will be using the same shared instance:

```java
Boolean a = false;
Boolean b = true;
Boolean c = false;
Boolean d = true;
System.out.println(a == c); // prints true, identical Boolean.FALSE
System.out.println(b == d); // prints true, identical Boolean.TRUE
```

In order to be distinguished, different `Boolean` variables need to be created with a constructor (which is deprecated):

```java
Boolean a = new Boolean(false);
Boolean b = new Boolean(true);
Boolean c = new Boolean(false);
Boolean d = new Boolean(true);
System.out.println(a == c);       // prints false, non-identical
System.out.println(a.equals(c));  // prints true, equal
System.out.println(b == d);       // prints false, non-identical
System.out.println(b.equals(d));  // prints true, equal
```

Now, upon ensuring that we have different `Boolean` objects, we can select it randomly:

```java
public static Boolean getTrueIndexRandomly(Boolean... flags) {
    List<Boolean> list = Arrays.asList(flags);
    // get indexes of flags whose values are true
    int[] indexes = IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                             .filter(list::get)
                             .toArray();
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomIndex = indexes[random.nextInt(indexes.length)];  // select one index
    System.out.print("random index=" + randomIndex);
    return flags[randomIndex];
}
```

Test:

```java
Boolean random;
System.out.println("Selecting from b, d");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.print("#" + (i + 1) + ": ");
    random = getTrueRandomly(a, b, c, d);
    System.out.println(" -> " + (random == b ? "b": "d"));
}

a = new Boolean(true);
System.out.println("Selecting from a, b, d");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    System.out.print("#" + (i + 1) + ": ");
    random = getTrueRandomly(a, b, c, d);
    System.out.println(" -> " + (random == a ? "a" : random == b ? "b" : "d"));
}
```

**Output**

```
Selecting from b, d
#1: random index=3 -> d
#2: random index=1 -> b
#3: random index=3 -> d
#4: random index=1 -> b
Selecting from a, b, d
#1: random index=3 -> d
#2: random index=1 -> b
#3: random index=1 -> b
#4: random index=0 -> a
```